# javascript to typescript: mix prototype based object with class based one

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, prototype

i'm trying to mix javascript prototype with class based, like this:

```js
function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Cat.prototype.purr = function(){
    console.log(`${this.name} purr`);
}
Cat.prototype.meow = function(){
    console.log(`${this.name} meow`);
}


class Tiger extends Cat {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name);
    }

    meow() {
        console.log(`${this.name} roar`);
    }
}
```

the JS code above is valid.
then I convert the code to typescript like this:

```js
function Cat(this : any, name : string) {
    this.name = name;
}
Cat.prototype.purr = function(){
    console.log(`${this.name} purr`);
}
Cat.prototype.meow = function(){
    console.log(`${this.name} meow`);
}


// error: Type '(this: any, name: string) => void' is not a constructor function type.
class Tiger extends Cat {
    constructor(name : string) {
        super(name);
    }

    meow() {
        console.log(`${this.name} roar`);
    }
}
```

the class Tiger doesn't accept the class Cat as its base class. (valid in JS but not in TS).
I cannot change the Cat to standard class syntax because I need the .prototype access to be pointed to another JS library.

anyone can fix the TS code above? maybe add some **.d.ts** definition.

Note: adding **// @ts-ignore** works but I cannot do that because the VS-code intellisense will not work.

Comment: "*I cannot change the Cat to standard class syntax because I need the .prototype access to be pointed to another JS library.*" - `class` syntax uses prototype objects in exactly the same way. Please be more specific about that constraint - you really *should* use `class Cat { … }` in TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could attempt to do something like this

```
interface CatClass {
  name: string
  purr(): void
  meow(): void

  new (name: string): CatClass
}

const Cat = function(this: CatClass, name: string) {
  this.name = name
} as unknown as CatClass
// Then add functions to prototype and everything should be fine
```

The question is why you are doing this in the first place, why not rewriting it as a normal class? There doesn't seem to be any info about how to type such function classes without this `as unknown as CatClass` thing (which seems like a little hack but well), maybe because no one has ever needed to do this, which I understand. Anyway after transpilation all classes become functions

Comment: well, actually i'm trying to make a jquery wrapper class. I need to doing JqueryWrapper.prototype = $.prototype . doing like this: class JqueryWrapper extends $ wouldn't work